# Online accounts doesn't get saved on Budgie 18.04 minimal

Tags: online-accounts, budgie

I'm trying to make the switch from Windows to Ubuntu permanently. My experience with Linux desktop environments is extremely limited but I have "hobbyist" experience with different kind of servers for the past 10 years at least. I've ran in to an issue though.

I installed Budgie 18.04 minimal and I'm trying to add "Online accounts" but they don't seem to actually get saved. For instance, trying to add a NextCloud account. I set up all the settings and press "Connect". It seems to validate the connection but it doesn't get saved. It will give me an error if I use the wrong credentials. And yes I've tried other accounts like Google and Facebook with the same result.
How would I go about to troubleshoot this? I am using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

[image: Adding an account]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Problem was that gnome-online-accounts was not installed with a minimal installation.

```
sudo apt install gnome-online-accounts
```

..followed with a reboot fixed the issue

*edit Also this should be fixed in the next 18.04.2 release due in jan/feb 2019 as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/+bug/1809264